# Can't get any VBA code to work when pasted into worksheet such as a worksheet change event - Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I can't seem to get "any" code to work when pasted into a Worksheet.  Here's an example of my code. It is to simply change the Sheet Tab color to Green if "Yes" is selected from a data validation drop-down list, otherwise set it to Red.  By default the Tab color is Yellow

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("C3").Value = "Yes" Then
    Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 4
Else
    Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 3
End If
End Sub
```

The Workbook is macro enabled (.xlsm)
The code is pasted into the Sheet with "Worksheet" and "Change" selected at top

This is just one code example.  I have other code to "hide/unhide a row(s) based on a cell value" as well as a few others and nothing runs.  I've followed the instructions that "everyone" has posted (which are the same exact steps) and for the life of me, I can't get anything to work.

Can anyone tell me what to check for.

Thank you in advance for anyone that can help. Greatly appreciated.
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address="$C$3" Then
If Range("C3").Value = "Yes" Then
    Me.Tab.Color = RGB(0,255,0)
Else
    Me.Tab.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, did this work for you? Do you've anymore questions?

Comment: bulbus, thank you for this, I really appreciate it! However, my "actual" problem is that any correct code that I place in the worksheet, doesn't work. Your code is perfect but it simply doesn't work. I'm missing something, a setting or switch and I can't figure it out. Do you understand what I mean? this is frustrating as heck

Answer (score 0):

You should specify whether Target changes and also you should narrow your target range so that it doesn't fire every time you change any cell other than your dropdown.
so your code should be like this in summary

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C3")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target.Address="$C$3" Then
    If Range("C3").Value = "Yes" Then
        Me.Tab.Color = RGB(0,255,0)
    Else
        Me.Tab.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
    End If
  End If
End IF
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for this, I really appreciate it!  However, my "actual" problem is that any correct code that I place in the worksheet, doesn't work.  Your code is perfect but it simply doesn't work.  I'm missing something, a setting or switch and I can't figure it out.  Do you understand what I mean?  this is frustrating as heck :(

Comment: can you give more info pls, i really dont understand what the problem is about